# OAuthException code: 1 publishing photos to a FB group via graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have an application to publish photos to many Facebook groups, one by one. It gets user_groups and publish_stream scopes in oauth dialog.
It was working so well until today, but it is now reporting an OAuthException code:1 message.
Someone has experienced the same error?

Comment: yes. i experiment the same error.. i test, and i can publish only in my timeline if you try see the photos of a friend, page, group you cant (and you cant publish to) https://grap.facebook.com/[id_friend,id_page,id_group]/photos <--- this ever fail. some issus reportet: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1430985030446221?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5273567f359eb3808359032

Answer (score 3):

Still a bug and the priority is MEDIUM:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/363009547168177
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/535574196527643
if more developers mention this might change to HIGH